# Etag decoding error when using awssdk s3 v2 with GCS and Minio gateway

Tags: java, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, aws-sdk, minio

I am currently migrating my Java codebase to use [S3 client v2 instead of old v1 client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/migration-guide/whats-different.html).

I'm interacting with the S3 API through a Minio gateway that sends/get objects to/from GCS (Google Cloud Storage).
The synchronous client was previously working fine but now I'm unable to do simple Put operations such as `PutObjectRequest` because the sdk client expects a MD5 hash in "eTag" field when it actually received a differently encoded hash. I am declaring my client as follows :

```java
AwsBasicCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(config.getKey(), config.getSecret());
     return S3Client.builder()
         .endpointOverride(URI.create(config.getEndpoint()))
         .region(Region.of(config.getRegion()))
         .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
         .serviceConfiguration(S3Configuration.builder().pathStyleAccessEnabled(true).build())
         .build();
```

And using it with a simple Put request such as :

```java
byte[] content = "THIS IS THE CONTENT".getBytes();
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.fromBytes(content);
PutObjectRequest build = PutObjectRequest.builder()
    .bucket(BUCKET)
    .key("test-file")
    .build();
s3Client.putObject(build, requestBody);
```

The error stacktrace is the following :

```
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (Invalid base 16 character: '-'). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK

    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:97)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleSuccessResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:100)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:70)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:58)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:41)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:64)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.doExecute(RetryableStage.java:113)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(RetryableStage.java:86)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:62)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:57)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:240)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:96)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:120)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:73)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:44)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.putObject(DefaultS3Client.java:3053)
    at com.airbus.geocloud.dm.client.storage.sync.SyncStorageClientIntegrationTest$Local.simplePut(SyncStorageClientIntegrationTest.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid base 16 character: '-'
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.internal.Base16Codec.pos(Base16Codec.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.internal.Base16Codec.decode(Base16Codec.java:66)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.internal.Base16Lower.decode(Base16Lower.java:65)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.checksums.ChecksumsEnabledValidator.validatePutObjectChecksum(ChecksumsEnabledValidator.java:131)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.SyncChecksumValidationInterceptor.afterUnmarshalling(SyncChecksumValidationInterceptor.java:88)
```

A few notes :

- I have done the same test directly on GCS and it's working perfectly (GCS is actually returning a MD5 hash) so it seems to be a Minio gateway issue.
- I was previously (when using client v1) using a "S3SignerType" override
- I have tried adding one of `Aws4Signer` or `AwsS3V4Signer` to my client configuration, without success

Environment:

- Minio:

```
Version: 2019-05-02T19:07:09Z
Release-Tag: RELEASE.2019-05-02T19-07-09Z
Commit-ID: 4b858b562a0887e10bfd0414dc87e68f1af31c3a
```

- Java SDK version: 2.5.25

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It actually was [a bug with Minio](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/7642) versions under `RELEASE.2019-05-23T00-29-34Z`, it has since [been fixed](https://github.com/minio/minio/pull/7643).